# Database Designing Issues

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a database  having Millions of records in three tables. Now i want to split these three tables in multiple tables to reduce redundancy and data duplication.

A lot of  records(Persons) have multiple city, address , telephone, fax.

So New tables will be 
Address,
 ,City 
,Postcode
 ,State
 ,Country
 ,Telephone
,Fax

My question is , Is it fine to have City, Postcode, State, Country, Telephone tables separately  or Just merge these tables in address table?

Comment: This belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To reduce redundancy, it is advisable to have separate tables for country, state and city. Though you can merge postcodes and telephone and address into single table.

Comment: i suggest make them all sepearte like dim.tables and all linked to fact -table with identity set on dim.tables having business keys??

Comment: I would recommend design based on situation. If your business is more for generate for reporting then don't split otherwise you have to join a lot of tables.

An example of understanding the complexity of your construct would be to simulate an algorithm to insert one new Person with phone-number: Select State-id by name and country. If found -> remember state-id, if not, insert new State. Select City-id by name and state. If found -> remember city-id, if not, insert new City. Select Postcode-id by postcode and city-id. If found -> remember postcode-id, if not, insert new Postcode.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate address, city, postcode, state, and country into a separate table as those are usually shared between multiple records. Please note though that it only makes sense if you store additional information for them, e.g. state name and abbreviation. Otherwise there's no point in having a separate table for e.g. state with only one column for state name.

As for phone numbers and faxes, they are usually not shared by different records and there's no need to separate them.

Comment: Agreed - have a "complete address" table (US/Canada only, though, essentially), and a "phone" table (where you have types - home, mobile, fax, etc).